# Why SvcUtil.exe does not generate References.cs if I pass /reference parameter?

Tags: svcutil.exe

I observe strange behavior of SvcUtils.exe.

If I pass there /reference parameter, it does not generate *.cs file for some reason.

```
C:\test>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcUtil.exe" /t:code http://localhost/Api/Common.svc /r:Api.dll
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost/Api/Common.svc' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Generating files...
C:\test\output.config
```

At the same time, if I remove the parameter, it generates it normally.

```
C:\test>"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\SvcUtil.exe" /t:code http://localhost/Api/Common.svc
Microsoft (R) Service Model Metadata Tool
[Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Communication Foundation, Version 4.0.30319.17929]
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Attempting to download metadata from 'http://localhost/Api/Common.svc' using WS-Metadata Exchange or DISCO.
Generating files...
C:\test\CommonService.cs
C:\test\output.config
```

Why?
How to get the classes from Api.dll that are used in Api.svc to be generated in CommonService.cs?

UPD. Let me add some details that seem to me obvious but nevertheless important. The Api.dll assemply includes classes marked with **[DataContract]** attribute with properties marked with **[DataMember]** attribute. These classes are returned from methods visible in Api.svc. My goal is to **reuse** the classes from Api.dll in generated proxy code.

Why I find this behavior strange? It generates proxy classes normally for services without reuse, but if I add /r parameter to reuse classes, it refuses to generate code at all. So the question is what is done wrong? What could be done wrong to get this behavior and how to do it right to achieve the goal?

UPD2. The most strange is that updating references from Visual Studio with checked "reuse" option works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem. I actually was using svcutil because Visual Studio gave me errors that the code for the WCF reference could not be created and gave no more information. I eventually enabled the warnings in VS which gave me more information. It turned out that I was referencing an assembly that itself references the WCF service. Because of that certain types are included twice. The mapping of the types then fails. What I did was I configured which assemblies were referenced. Thereby I only selected the WCF service and then standard .NET System assemblies. I also disabled generating data contracts (I had it enabled just to try that out) and was able to build.

Put short: make sure that the types that you want to use are referenced only once.